# 3-way switch replacement mystery: can I solve it without a meter?

Tags: wiring, switch

3-way switch replacement mystery:

I wanted to replace the old, beige toggle switches in our kitchen and hall with Leviton Decora white paddle switches.

**The kitchen** was easy, just removed the wire from the old switch and immediately put it on the corresponding terminal on the new switch. Dark terminal is common, the 2 brass ones are travelers, ground is ground. Easy peasy worked like a charm.

**The hallway**: the switches are identical to each other but not like the kitchen, they are older. They don't have ground terminals - what's up with that? There are ground wires passing through each box so I tied into them. The terminals on the switches are all alike - dull brass slotted screw head. I figured if I moved old wires to corresponding position on the new switch the odds would be at least 50:50 it would be correct, **Nope**. One switch has 1 red, 1 white, 1 black - the other switch 1 white, 2 black. AND inside the box that has 1 white, 2 black, I can see a white wire connected to a red wire, and not connected to anything else. That doesn't seem right... I have not looked inside the light fixture to see what's going on there.

Any explanation for the red and white wires tied together?

Can I find the solution without a meter?

My switches are now wired this way (*sorry, no pictures, I put the switches back in the wall and DW won't let me turn the power off to troubleshoot*.)

**Switch right**, looking at switch as installed:

1. top right terminal: traveler, black
2. bottom right terminal: common, white
3. bottom left terminal: traveler, black

(*this box has a red and white wire connected together tucked away in the back*)

**Switch left**, looking at switch as installed:

1. top right terminal: traveler, black
2. bottom right terminal: common, white
3. bottom left terminal: traveler, RED

My guess: put the white on traveler, put the black on common.

Comment: Switch positions/terminals are not standard. you have to look at the diagrams on the boxes to know where/how to hook up the switch. We're going to need more information and pictures are always helpful. Can you install the old switch as it was before?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you had the right idea about screw color, but worrying about physical position was a dead-end. There's no standard. Every manufacturer changes the screw positions on every model every week.

Don't sweat the differing wire colors.  Wire colors are also completely meaningless in 3-ways since all 3 wires are often hot.   The three colors are due to the limitations of using multi-wire cable.  In conduit, when I pick the colors, travelers are the 2 yellow wires.  There's no Code requirement that "travelers must be color X and color Y" because there are *other* Code requirements that certain *other* wires must be certain colors.

The 2 travelers can be determined by the fact that they are always in the same cable.

If all 3 wires are in the same cable, then look for one wire that is hot at all times regardless of the position of the other 3-way - that is common.

If that is not present, then look for the two wires that change hotness when the other 3-way is thrown - those are travelers.

I'm a big believer in marking travelers both with yellow tape. There is no need to distinguish 2 travelers from each other.  But 2 yellows in a box is distinctive.